# Azure DevOps pipeline decorator doesn't inject a custom task unless the latter is manually added once

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-decorator

I've authored an Azure DevOps extension contributing a task and a pipeline decorator. When I use the decorator template below(example from [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops)) then the CmdLine task is injected to every job in my pipeline as expected:

```
steps:
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Run my script (injected from decorator) - post'
    inputs:
      script: 'echo decorator'
```

But if I modify the template to inject my custom task(installed by my extension) as below:

```
steps:
  - task: MicroFocus1.alm-octane-integration.octane-start-task.octane-start-task@1
    displayName: 'ALM Octane Pipeline Start'
    inputs:
      OctaneService: Octane
```

then the task is not injected to every job unless I add it manually to a single job - then it is injected to the rest.
Why can't it be injected without adding it manually?

Thanks,
Moshe.

Comment: Do you mean - you have a yaml template with the extension, then, in another yaml you call the template and the extension not injected?

Comment: See this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops. If I use Microsoft's CmdLine@2 task it works fine but if I use my own task added by my extension it's not injected unless I add it manually to any job then it's injected to the other jobs. Looks like the system is not aware of my task until it's manually added.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually the problem was an error in my YAML fragment - I forgot to wrap the OctaneService parameter value of my task with quotes. It should be:

```
OctaneService: 'Octane'
```

I'd recommend Azure DevOps developers to give any indication why a pipeline decorator fails (system.debugContext didn't provide any clue).

Comment: I've faced the same issue. As quoting isn't needed for the normal pipeline, it seems to be required for decorators.

Comment: I found out this answer doesn't work decorators targeting classic RM pipelines. Possibly a serviceconnection's guid would work, partially. But not tested, I stuck with hardcoding the serviceconnection name in the task itself. Ugly, but it's better than a guid.